# help me explain problem on sylvester nullity thm

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
I cannot explain the option c and d. Can someone please explain it better ,how the left side inequality has been brought about in c and b options' explanation.

Comment: What is denoted  η?

Comment: Nullity I suppose